# nmap-python won't install properly on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

I am trying to scan my network for connected mac addresses and found that `nmap` could do the trick. Since I want to monitor connections over time, I want to use my Raspberry Pi which has no use until now to do the task on its own in an interval I don't know yet.
I obviously chose Python (which I am new to) to do the tasks I mentioned above.

My Problem begins with installing `nmap`. I installed it for the Terminal via `sudo apt-get install nmap` which didn't work well, because it's not a Python module, duh.
I then installed `nmap-python` via `sudo apt-get install nmap-python` and tried to import it in Python (at first via the shell) with `import nmap`

which gave me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nmap
ImportError: No module named nmap
```

(same thing for the import via a .py-script)

If I list all my Modules via `help('modules')`, it shows several modules and one of them is `nmap`

...what's the problem now? I don't get it. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may come from the version of Python. It's possible that the module nmap-python you installed is for Python 2 and you are using the pyshell for Python 3, or the inverse.

Comment: that was the problem...oh my god - too easy I guess. Thank you very much!